# Use of "anisotropically"

Tags: mathematics

Suppose a function of two real variables f(x,y) is scaled as f(ax,by), where a may not equal b. Is it correct to say that f is "scaled anisotropically." Is it correct to use "anisotropically" as an adverb?

Comment: Are you asking us about correct mathematical terminology or about the use of English? *Anisotropically* is certainly a well-formed adverb.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: I found this after answering no, that's wrong :(  http://www.verycomputer.com/5_465da7897cb84d41_1.htm

Comment: Please include the research you've done, and consider if your question suits our Maths site better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to a domain specific site, namely http://mathematics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have ever seen the word *anisotropically* used, but this seems like the canonical usage.  Anyone who understands isotropism will correctly interpret the sentence, which I think should be the desideratum.

**Edit:** having read the comments, I am now thinking that perhaps *anisomorphically* would convey your meaning better.

Comment: I'd go with *anisomorphically*. *Isotropy* has more to do with spatial distribution.